# AngularJs Component usage as Attribute

Tags: angularjs, components

I've created a Component in NG1 and I would like to use it as attribute like "A" restrict in directive. Is this possible in NG1, because in NG2 Component it is possible. Otherwise I've to use a good old directive instead.

I don't want to use

```
<my-comp></my-comp>
```

I want to use with Component in angularjs 1

```
<div my-comp></div>
```

Comment: you cannot use component like. In angularjs 1 components are restricted to elements only.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#comparison-between-directive-definition-and-component-definition